# What kind of error after run docker from jenkins?

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I run jenkins pipeline with jenkinsfile:

```
node ('PXE_Sparrow')
{
     docker.image('onvif').run()
}
```

But get error ->

```
 [C:\Jenkins\workspace\RunTestsOnvifSDK_develop] Running shell script
 process apparently never started in 
 C:\Jenkins\workspace\RunTestsOnvifSDK_develop@tmp\durable-e7dda884
 Cannot contact PXE_Sparrow: java.io.IOException: 
 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: 
 C:\Jenkins\workspace\RunTestsOnvifSDK_develop@tmp\durable-e7dda884\output.txt
```

why can there be such a mistake?

Comment: Cannot contact PXE_Sparrow, do you have a slave with this as label?

Comment: @lvthillo Yes. And jenkins creates on this node file script.sh containing the command  docker run

Comment: What happens if you just create a pipeline job with your pipeline in it without specifying a node, just a basic docker.image and run?

Comment: On jenkins machine not was installed docker, and because jenkins showed error - docker not found

Comment: @lvthillo but node PXE_Sparrow it is Windows with docker. 
And i finded place of problem. docker.image() is running sh on windows and sh not work.